# Write a part of the class as XML

Tags: c#, xml

Hello, I would like to ask you a question.

I created a Person class and I wrote persons name, surname, id and image.

Now I want to save this class as .xml with image. I found a solution for the save a class as .xml but it does not save any image into .xml file.

```
private void SaveasXML()
{
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BindingList<Person>));
     FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Application.StartupPath + "\\Data\\Person.xml");
     serializer.Serialize(fileStream, New_Xml_Person);
}
```

I want to save all information with image into .xml file. To save image as .xml file it should be converted to `base64string`. I know that but I could not use it.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the actual image saved to the XML file or do you only want the path saved?

Comment: How do you store the image in the class?. Can you share your Person clsss code?

Comment: A Image can be saved as converted base64strings. Last get-set part of my Person class:

  [XmlElementAttribute("Picture")]
  public byte[] PictureByteArray
  {
   get 
   { 
    if (picture != null)
    {
     TypeConverter BitmapConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(picture.GetType());
     return (byte[]) BitmapConverter.ConvertTo(picture, typeof(byte[]));     
    }
    else
     return null;
   }
   
   set 
   { 
    if (value != null)
     picture = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(value)); 
    else
     picture = null; 
   }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a byte[] ImageBuffer property to your Person class, which contains the binary image data. You would then also set the XmlIgnore attribute on the Image property to suppress its (de)serialization, and set XmlElement("Image") on the ImageBuffer properties to (de)serialize it as Image.

Updated answer:

```
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()] 
    public Bitmap Picture { get { return picture; } set { picture = value; } } 

    [XmlElementAttribute("Picture")] 
    public byte[] PictureByteArray { 
        get { 
            if (picture != null) { 
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                     picture.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                     return ms.ToArray();
                }
            } else return null; 
        } 
        set { 
            if (value != null) 
            {
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(value))
                                {
                                   picture = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
                                } 
            }
            else picture = null; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I changed text to:
[XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
  public Bitmap Picture
  {
   get { return picture; }
   set { picture = value; }
  }
[XmlElementAttribute("Picture")]
  public byte[] PictureByteArray
  {
   get 
   { 
    if (picture != null)
    {
     TypeConverter BitmapConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(picture.GetType());
     return (byte[]) BitmapConverter.ConvertTo(picture, typeof(byte[]));     
    }
    else
     return null;
   }
   
   set 
   { 
    if (value != null)
     picture = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(value)); 
    else
     picture = null; 
   }
  }

But it didnt work.